# Why am I getting: "Future exception was never retrieved" error

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, pyppeteer

I am using asyncio and pyppeteer to test scraping sites. Currently I have:

```
browser = await launch(
        args=[f'--proxy-server={proxyUrl}'],
        headless=True,
        autoClose=False
    )
```

to launch the browser. I am using `autoClose=False` as when I ran it as `True` I was left with hanging Chromium processes.

After struggling with many network errors, and hanging processes the best way I found this to be the best way:

```
def close_browser(browser):
    browser.process.terminate()
```

However, sometimes the operation will result in no errors being thrown, or up to 18 errors. All the errors are:

```
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=NetworkError('Protocol error Target.sendMessageToTarget: Target closed.')>
pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol error Target.sendMessageToTarget: Target closed.
```

**This is the output when I looped through the code 10 times:**

```
Completed  Number 4

Completed  Secondary

Completed  Primary

Completed  Number 5
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=NetworkError('Protocol error Target.sendMessageToTarget: Target closed.')>
pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol error Target.sendMessageToTarget: Target closed.

Completed  Tertiary
Done
Running all tasks took  8.363972902297974
All tasks successfully ran.

Completed  Secondary

Completed  Tertiary

Completed  Number 4

Completed  Primary

Completed  Number 5
Done
Running all tasks took  9.243869304656982
All tasks successfully ran.

Completed  Tertiary

Completed  Primary

Completed  Number 4

Completed  Number 5

Completed  Secondary
Done
Running all tasks took  8.441104650497437
All tasks successfully ran.

Completed  Number 5

Completed  Primary

Completed  Secondary

Completed  Number 4

Completed  Tertiary
Done
Running all tasks took  8.054714918136597
All tasks successfully ran.

Completed  Number 5

Completed  Number 4

Completed  Secondary

Completed  Tertiary

Completed  Primary
Done
Running all tasks took  8.639416217803955
All tasks successfully ran.

Completed  Number 5

Completed  Secondary

Completed  Number 4

Completed  Tertiary

Completed  Primary
Done
Running all tasks took  8.757359027862549
All tasks successfully ran.

Completed  Tertiary

Completed  Number 5

Completed  Primary

Completed  Number 4

Completed  Secondary
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=NetworkError('Protocol error Target.sendMessageToTarget: Target closed.')>
pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol error Target.sendMessageToTarget: Target closed.
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=NetworkError('Protocol error Target.sendMessageToTarget: Target closed.')>
pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol error Target.sendMessageToTarget: Target closed.
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=NetworkError('Protocol error Target.sendMessageToTarget: Target closed.')>
pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol error Target.sendMessageToTarget: Target closed.
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=NetworkError('Protocol error Target.sendMessageToTarget: Target closed.')>
pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol error Target.sendMessageToTarget: Target closed.
Done
Running all tasks took  8.711585521697998
All tasks successfully ran.

Completed  Number 4

Completed  Tertiary

Completed  Secondary

Completed  Number 5
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=NetworkError('Protocol error Target.sendMessageToTarget: Target closed.')>
pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol error Target.sendMessageToTarget: Target closed.
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=NetworkError('Protocol error Target.sendMessageToTarget: Target closed.')>
pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol error Target.sendMessageToTarget: Target closed.

Completed  Primary
Done
Running all tasks took  8.28357720375061
All tasks successfully ran.

Completed  Tertiary

Completed  Secondary

Completed  Number 5

Completed  Primary

Completed  Number 4
Done
Running all tasks took  8.737911939620972
All tasks successfully ran.

Completed  Secondary

Completed  Number 5

Completed  Number 4

Completed  Primary

Completed  Tertiary
Done
Running all tasks took  8.866266965866089
All tasks successfully ran.
```